# before pseudoelement in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, pseudo-element

It appears to me that Chrome does not treat "before" pseudoelement as a part of an element. More precisely, I have CSS definition

```
.myclass:before{content:"A";}
```

and HTML code

```
<a href="blah" class="myclass">B</a>
```

In Chrome the result is a hyperlink "AB" but only "B" is actually clickable. In Firefox and Opera the whole "AB" is a link, and my reading of CSS standard indicates that Chrome is wrong here.

Am I right in assuming that this is Chrome's bug? Is there a simple and clean workaround?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you can work around it with:

```
.myclass {
    display: inline-block
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SUKYw/

Looks like a Chrome bug - Safari does not have the same problem.

Comment: The workaround appears to work, and to have no ill side-effects in other browsers (I checked Opera, Firefox, and IE). Many thanks!