# Getting clicks on css :pseudo-elements

Tags: html, css, webkit, pseudo-element

I'm trying to make a custom checkbox, so I made something like that : http://jsfiddle.net/wQdUn/2/

The problem is that, on WebKit based browsers, the checkbox is toggled only when clicking on the content of the `<span>`, not on the box itself, while in Firefox I get the behavior I expect.

So I have two questions:

- Which one is the *right* behavior (i.e. the one conform to specifications)?
- How do I get the result I want in both browsers (and others...)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about the first question, but if you make the `span` an inline block too, it'll work as you expect in WebKit browsers. See http://jsfiddle.net/wQdUn/5

Comment: [Yup.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480495/before-pseudoelement-in-chrome)

Comment: @thirtydot: The original fiddle here didn't work in Chrome or Safari. I get the feeling WebKit is trolling us sometimes.

Comment: [The original fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wQdUn/2/) works in Safari 5.0.3/Windows 7, but doesn't work in Safari 5.1/Server 2008. I guess I need to update Safari on my actual computer so it can break properly..

Answer (score 0):

For those who come to this topic form google:

Safari 6.0.4(8536.29.13) still got this problem, you need to set `inline-block` on pseudo-element to make click work.

Chrome switched to Blink as it's rendering engine, so this problem didn't happen on chrome any more(26.0.1410.65).